# Image rotation in the direction of input values

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation

I'm trying to rotate an image in a circular motion both clockwise and counter clockwise with specific input values.

what i'm trying to achieve is

rotate the circle in clockwise motion if
1. input angle is positive
2. positive input angle is lower than the old positive input angle.Ex. If old angle is 22 degree and the new angle is 12 degrees, the image should rotate clockwise from 22 to 12.

rotate the image counter clockwise if
1. the input angle is negetive
2. negetive input angle is higher than the old angle. Ex. If the old angle is -22 degrees and the new angle is -44 degrees, the image should rotate counter clockwise from -22 to -44.

Any pointers, tips or reference code on how to get this done would be of great help!
Thanks!

Comment: Need specification, i think. Are you looking for an element to display the image rotatedly, or are you trying to generate a new rotated image, pixel by pixel (which would propably be imperfect, but would work if you don't let errors accumulate).

Comment: Have you already tried to solve this problem? Are you doing homework?

Comment: @TheHowlingHoaschd I'm trying to rotate the element. I'm able to rotate the image based on x and -x values but cant seen to get it working for this particular logic where i can set the image to rotate clockwise or counter clockwise to the specification

Comment: @ElmoDev001 I haven't been able to solve this problem yet and no its not a homework.:)

Comment: By the way, I'm using animation to get the image rotate smoothly from old to new angle